# How to add more than 5000 items in a SharePoint list using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom, sharepoint-list

I am trying to add 5000 items in a SharePoint list using JSOM. But unfortunately didn't get any luck.

```
function createListItem() {


        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DummyList');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        for(var i = 0;i<5000;i++)
        {
        this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('ItemNumber', i);
        oListItem.update();
        }
        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {

        console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());

    }


    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

But after some time server stops responding. I know there is something called Threshold limit. But according to the requirement more than 5000 items should be stored in one take only. I have no idea where I am making mistake. Please help.

Comment: You can try REST api with async:false so it will add your list items in a sync manner. In JSOM it works in async mode that's why you might be facing error.

Comment: Could you please give one small example @Dikesh Gandhi ?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with REST API with sync manner. Please see code as below:

```
for(var i=0;i<5000;i++)
{
    var item = {
    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.ABCListItem"},
    ItemNumber: i.toString()
    };

    $.ajax({
    url: fullurl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ABC')/items",
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
    });
}
```

**Reference:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried it and its working. Thanks [Dikesh Gandhi](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/29853/dikesh-gandhi).